# Difference between /etc/security/limits.conf and /proc/$PID/limits

Tags: ubuntu

My configuration in `/etc/security/limits.conf` is

```
* soft nofile 60000
* hard nofile 60000
```

I run nginx in ubuntu.after reboot the ubuntu, `ulimit -n` is 60000, but

```
cat /proc/`ps -elf | grep nginx | grep 'master process' | awk '{print $4}'`/limits| grep 'open files'
```

the answer is 1024, why not 60000?

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/security/limits.conf` is read by the PAM module `pam_limits.so` at login.

But when nginx is started at boot, it never passes through a login procedure, so PAM never has a chance to make any ulimit changes to the nginx process or any of its parent processes.

If your `nginx` is started by a script, then you should add the ulimit commands to the script:

```
ulimit -H -n 60000
ulimit -S -n 60000
```

If `nginx` is started by a `systemd` .service file, use `systemctl edit nginx.service`, and add this line to the `[Service]` section of the file:

```
LimitNOFILE=60000:60000
```

`systemctl edit some.service` will automatically take the original service file from `[/usr]/lib/systemd` tree and place the modified version under `/etc/systemd` instead. Any files in `/etc/systemd` will override any files with the same name located in `[/usr]/lib/systemd` tree.

It will also cause the service configuration to be automatically reloaded, so you don't need to use `systemctl daemon-reload` manually.

Comment: You should use `systemctl edit foo.service` instead of manually copy-creating override files.

Comment: Good point, edited my answer.

Comment: Beaten by muru.  I was going to say the same.  And also note that you missed out an Upstart job file, the actual most likely alternative to a systemd unit.  There's a lot more on this subject on AskUbuntu.  Witness https://askubuntu.com/questions/941617/ , https://askubuntu.com/questions/635110/ , and many others.

Comment: I'm actually not too familiar with Upstart as used on Ubuntu; feel free to edit my answer to add specifics on Upstart.